# Understanding the difference between matrix indices and image coordinates in context of ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, functions, matrix, image

In *Mathematica* help it's written that:

> `ListDensityPlot[array]` ->  generates a smooth density plot from an `array` of values.

There is also an example:

```
 ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

I understand when the input is in the form of $ \{ x, y, f(x,y)\}$, what this function 
does. But, I really cannot understand what this function does when it has an array as 
an input.

Comment: What does the forth element mean in the example above? I think for density plot we mush have two value for coordinate and one value for the intensity or density in that coordinate.
But in the example above I cannot find such a pattern.

Comment: please note the preamble in the documentation for the example: "Use an array of values to define heights for a density". See also ReliefPlot and see the effect of arrays of various sizes eg 7x 5 or whatever you like. Look through all the examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer about the pattern you are missing:

each value in an array is the value that generates color for Integer coordinates like (1,1) between those an interpolation is done by `ListDensityPlot`.

### Matrices world:

- **First index** refers to **rows**
- **First row** is the **top one**

### Graphics world

- **First coordinate** refers to **"columns"**
- **First "row"** refers to the **bottom one**.

[image]

```
Panel@Grid[{
   {MatrixForm@array,
    Grid[MapIndexed[
      Framed[#, 
        Background -> 
         Directive[Opacity@.8, Blend["Rainbow", #2[[1]]/4]], 
        ImageSize -> 35 {1, 1}, Alignment -> Center, 
        BaseStyle -> {Bold, White}] &, array, {2}], 
     Spacings -> 1.5 {1, 1}]
    ,
    ListDensityPlot[array,
     BaseStyle -> 24, Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> White, 
     PlotRangePadding -> .5,
     Epilog -> {MapIndexed[
        Inset[Framed[#, 
           Background -> 
            Directive[Opacity[4/#], Blend["Rainbow", #2[[1]]/4]], 
           ImageSize -> 35 {1, 1}, Alignment -> Center, 
           BaseStyle -> {Bold, White}], #2] &, array, {2}]},
     ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 45]
    
    }}, Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> 3]
```

Comment: @Kuba. Thank you for your elegant and beautiful answer.

Comment: @yashar I'm glad I could help :) Good luck.