# What's the most precise way to compose Graphics[] objects with images?

Tags: graphics

I get the basic idea of using ImageCompose[], but I seem to be missing something, making me wonder if there's a better way.

The first thing that's a little confusing is that if I make a graphics object, apparently neither the size nor position I give to Graphics has any effect on where the Graphics object ends up in the image when I use ImageCompose:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
ImageDimensions@img

a = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{5, 5}, .1]}];
ImageCompose[img, a]
```

[image]

though I guess that kind of makes sense because it's relative. So I know I can used scaled, like so:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
imgdim = ImageDimensions@img

a = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{5, 5}, .1]}, ImageSize -> First@imgdim/10];
b = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{5, 5}, .1]}, ImageSize -> First@imgdim/10];
ImageCompose[img, {a, b}, {Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

But I get a little confused when I want to put a line on the image. I can't figure out a way of doing it that doesn't involve creating the line and then awkwardly scaling it, something like:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
imgdim = ImageDimensions@img

a = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{5, 5}, .1]}, ImageSize -> First@imgdim/8];
b = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{5, 5}, .1]}, ImageSize -> First@imgdim/8];
c = Graphics[{Red, Thickness@.02, Line[{{0, 0}, imgdim}]}, 
   ImageSize -> First@imgdim];
ImageCompose[img, {a, b, c}, {Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
  Scaled[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

(to be honest, I don't even fully get what's going on here, since it seems like I made the Line c the same size as the Lena image, but it only goes halfway across...)

Anyway, is there a less awkward way of doing this? I thought maybe Epilog would be the way but I can't see where I'd put it... I'd like to just be able to use the same coordinates as the image and directly plot Graphics[] objects onto the image. How can I do this?

Comment: see this to understand the difference of image coordinates and graphics coordinates: [47555](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47555/5478). Also, this seems to be related: [Overlaying location pointer on to a png file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29441/5478)

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to use `Inset` that you can use to include your image in a Graphics. If you set up the coordinates correctly, you should get correct results.

Everything depends on how you define *pixel position* meaning if the center of your pixels is on half steps or if you want to have the center on integer positions, but you can adjust this as you like. Let me give a small demo with an 20x20 image:

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {20, 20}];
{nx, ny} = ImageDimensions[img];

Graphics[{
  Inset[img, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {nx, ny}],
  White, Line[{{2, 2}, {nx - 1, ny - 1}}],
  Green,
  Point[{14.5, 10.5}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{1, nx}, {1, ny}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

Long time ago, when `Image` was in the distant future, the method of displaying pixel data was using `Raster`. This of course still works and both `Inset` and `Raster` will produce a `RasterBox` in the output expression. Remember that image coordinates have a reversed y-axis and if you use `Raster` you need to take care of that:

```
Graphics[{Raster[Reverse@ImageData[img]], White, Green, 
  Table[Point[{i, i}], {i, 1, nx - 1}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Inset` isn't necessary: "`Raster[array,{{xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymax}}]` specifies that the raster should be taken to fill the rectangle `Rectangle[{xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymax}]` [>>](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html#5548073)." Probably it is also more efficient.

Comment: AFAIK, `Raster` is the very old implementation of representing images in Mathematica. We used it for years in image processing to display results. I will edit my answer. The reason for suggesting `Inset` is that it has greater flexibility and if you look at the output expression, you'll find that both `Inset` and `Raster` produce a `RasterBox`.

Comment: Why not `HighlightImage`?

Comment: @Batracos [Good luck](https://youtu.be/GhhlmidD1tw) with that. I use it sometimes for annotating images with meta-data, but I found so many glitches in it, that I've basically given up on it. Look for instance [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89156/187) just to give an example.

Comment: @halirutan please give it another try! I spent a reasonable amount of time to take it over and refactor it completely to avoid rasterization whenever possible.
`HighlightImage[img, {Opacity[1], Green, Disk[{0, 0}, 20], 
  Disk[imgdim, 20], Red, Line[{{0, 0}, imgdim}]}]`

Comment: Also, to go from image to Graphics you may want to use ``Image`ToGraphicsRaster``

Comment: @Batracos Yeah right, keep me in the dark who you are to make me feel embarrassed afterwards that I thought you were *some user* who came across `HighlightImage` without thoroughly testing it :)
What a luck we have Google. Good to know that you polished `ImageHighlight` because it is indeed a very nice function especially for me when I have to highlight cell images for other scientists. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @halirutan I do not have nearly enough reputation here to boast about anything. Never tried to keep it secret either = )